# Is it possible to add paths to the PATH environment variable through serverless.yml?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

When I create an AWS Lambda Layer, all the contents / modules of my zip file go to `/opt/` when the AWS Lambda executes. This easily becomes cumbersome and frustrating because I have to use absolute imports on all my lambdas. Example:

```
import json
import os
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("dynamodb_layer.customer", "/opt/dynamodb_layer/customer.py")
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

def fetch(event, context):

    CustomerManager = module.CustomerManager
    customer_manager = CustomerManager()

    body = customer_manager.list_customers(event["queryStringParameters"]["acquirer"])

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        "body": json.dumps(body)
    }

    return response
```

So I was wondering, is it possible to add these /opt/paths to the PATH environment variable by beforehand through serverless.yml? In that way, I could just `from dynamodb_layer.customer import CustomerManager`, instead of that freakish ugliness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've Lambda layer for Python3.6 runtime. My my_package.zip structure is:

```
my_package.zip
 - python
   - lib
     - python3.6
       - site-packages
         - customer
```

All dependencies are in `build` folder in project root:
e.g. `build/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/customer`

Relevant section of my serverless.yml

```
layers:
  my_package:
    path: build             
    compatibleRuntimes:     
      - python3.6
```

In my Lambda I import my package like I would do any other package:
`import customer`

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to set the path in serverless? I have a bunch of files that I don't want to have to zip up in a specific directory structure, but I'd like them to end up in `/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shared`. Is there a way to do this without organizing them in that same directory structure in git?

Comment: @Craig Your build script can manipulate the directories in any way it sees fit, before packaging them into a zip file.
This is typically called 'staging'. In this case, your build would create a directory called 'python' then copy required files and package-dies into it, before creating the zip and uploading it as a layer. See my answer for example !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your PYTHONPATH env var?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5944201/6529424

Have you tried adding to sys.path?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257807/6529424

Comment: These are not the idiomatic ways to add import-able modules and packages, using Lambda Layers. See below.

Answer (score 0):

In the zip archive, the module needs to be placed the in a `python` subdirectory so that when it is extracted as a layer in Lambda, it is located in `/opt/python`. That way you'll be able to directly import your module without the need for `importlib`.

It's [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) or see [this detailed blogpost](https://medium.com/@adhorn/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d) from an AWS dev evangelist for more.

Comment: The links you provide did not seem explicit enough for my need to use my own package(s) - hence I have written things up a little more directly in my own answer below,

Comment: Good for you mate. You don't have to run around spamming everyone's answers though...

Comment: Sorry you feel annoyed, @milan - I was in the middle of the issue myself, and thought I would add some extra info for the use of others. It was by no means "spam" or self-promotion. And I try to give credit where it's due. If you had new detail for a SO problem, I trust you would doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Setting of PYTHONPATH variable is not required, as long as you place items correctly inside the zip file.

Simple modules, and package directories, these should be placed inside a directory "python", and then the whole python/ placed into the zip file for uploading to AWS as a layer. Don't forget to add the "compatible runtimes" (eg Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 ...) settings for the layers.

So as an example:

```
python/
- my_module.py
- my_package_dir
-- __init__.py
-- package_mod_1.py
-- package_mod_2.py
```

which then get included in the zip file.

```
zip -r my_layer_zip.zip python/
```

The modules can then be imported without any more ado, when accessed as a layer:

```
....
import my_module
from my_package.package_mod_2 import mod_2_function
....
```

You can see the package structure from within the lambda if you look at '/opt/python/' which will show my_module.py, my_package/ etc., this is easily tested using the AWS Lambda test function, assuming the layer is attached to the function (or else the code will error)

```
import json
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement

    dir_list = os.listdir('/opt/python/')

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!'),
        'event': json.dumps(event),
        '/opt/python/': dir_list
    }
```