# error installing tensorflow with pip install

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pip, data-science

i wrote on the cmd: pip install tensorflow==2.1.0 --user
it correctly donwload all the packages but in the end it say:

```
WARNING: The scripts estimator_ckpt_converter.exe, saved_model_cli.exe, tensorboard.exe, tf_upgrade_v2.exe, tflite_convert.exe, toco.exe and toco_from_protos.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
```

and then:

```
Successfully installed gast-0.2.2 tensorflow-2.1.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.1.0``
```

anyway, if i write a code and i try tu use tensorflow it doesn't work

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

the error that i get is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\users\franc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
        from . _api.v2 import audio
    ImportError: cannot import name 'audio' from 'tensorflow_core._api.v2' (C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Sho w the code what are you trying to do

Comment: i edit the question and i add the code

Comment: The path "C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts" it exists? and with permission?

Comment: yes, it exists. what do you mean with: permission?

Comment: Its probably just a warning. You should just reference the location where the scripts  are at since it is not in the default directory. Simply the directory to your search path should solve the issue I think. This could be done from CMD path or using sys.path. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944176/how-can-i-add-a-default-path-to-look-for-python-script-files-in

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Have you added `'C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts'` to `PATH`?

Comment: perhaps it is the version of tensorflow not accepted. Try installing version 1.14.

Comment: @FlyingTeller how can i do that?

Comment: @FrancescoDeSantis Right click `This PC` in windows explorer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings (Left side) -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables (on the bottom) -> select `Path` and hit Edit -> Select New and paste `C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts`, then hit `ok`, restart your system and then try to run your code again

Comment: ok, now i don't have any warning during the installation but, if i try to use keras package or to import tensorflow i got this error

Comment: Using TensorFlow backend.
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Comment: i have edited the question for adding the full message of error